# phoneGap Get JSON data from url and store the data in SQLite database (PhoneGap)

Tags: android, cordova

I m newbie in phoneGap. I wanna simple two page app. On first app we will get JSON data and then store it in phoneGap database(SQLite). then redirect to second page where we can use the data from phoneGap database. 
I have searched a lot but haven't got any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of jquery [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for retrieving Json from server

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'yoururl',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                // iterate over data and save it to DB
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        });
```

For database part you can check this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) which explains how to store and retrieve from database